# How to put object in bundle Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to pass data between to fragments, i use bundle for this, this is how it looks

```
  override fun onClick(model: CheckListModel) {
        var bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putSerializable("data",model)
        val fragment = MainCheckListPageFragment()
        fragment.arguments = bundle

    }
```

I have this problem

[image]

this is my data class CheckListModel

```
data class CheckListModel (
    val checkListName: String,
    val checkListCount: Int,
    val checkListPoints: List<CheckListPoints>,
    val checkListResult: Int,
    val description: String
        )
data class CheckListPoints(
    var correctly: Boolean,
    var requirement: String,
    var passed: Boolean,
): Serializable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid now, problem was that i use "Serializable" only for CheckListPoints class, but not for CheckListModel call

```
data class CheckListModel (
    val checkListName: String,
    val checkListCount: Int,
    val checkListPoints: List<CheckListPoints>,
    val checkListResult: Int,
    val description: String
        ):Serializable
data class CheckListPoints(
    var correctly: Boolean,
    var requirement: String,
    var passed: Boolean,
): Serializable
```

this is solution